# How do I perform this code using apply statements instead of this for loop?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, ggplot2, apply

I have a list  of dataframes where each column in the df corresponds to the evaluation of a function values from different numeric vectors of the same length.
Each list object(dataframe) is generated with a different function

I would like to iterate through each list object (dataframe) to
  1. Generate a plot for each list object(dataframe), with columns as data series.
  2. Generate a new list of new dataframes which contains a column for each column mean from the original dataframe

The below code is functional, but is there a better way to use apply statements and avoid the for loop?

```
plots <- list()
trait.estimate <- list()

 for(i in 1:length(component.estimation)) {  #outter loop start
  component.estimation[[i]]$hr <- hr #add hr vector to end of dataframe 
  temporary.df <- melt(component.estimation[[i]] ,  id.vars = 'hr', variable.name = 'treatment')

 #Store a plot of each df
plots[[i]] <- ggplot(temporary.df, aes(hr , value), group = treatment, colour = treatment, fill = treatment) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = treatment, fill = treatment))+
  geom_line(aes(colour= treatment, linetype = treatment))+
  ggtitle( names(component.estimation)[i])+  #title to correspond to trait
  theme_classic()

  #Generate column averages for each df
trait.estimate[[i]] <- apply(component.estimation[[i]] ,2, mean)
trait.estimate[[i]] <- as.data.frame(trait.estimate[[i]])
trait.estimate[[i]]$treatment <- row.names(trait.estimate[[i]])
  } #outter loop close
```

Comment: sample data needed please

Comment: Your `for` loop looks fine to me, I wouldn't worry about transitioning to `lapply`. Personally, I think `lapply` is great when you want to do something simple, but when you want something more complicated, (or to do multiple things at once) a `for` loop makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `for` loop looks fine to me, I wouldn't worry about transitioning to `lapply`. Personally, I think `lapply` is great when you want to do something simple, but when you want something more complicated, a for loop can be just as readable.

The only real change I'd make is to use `colMeans` rather than `apply(., 2, mean)`. I also might break apart the `trait.estimate` part and the plotting part as they seem wholly separate operations. Seems nicer organizationally.

As an example, pulling out the `trait.estimate` calculations would look like this:

```
# inside for loop version
trait.estimate[[i]] <- colMeans(component.estimation[[i]])
trait.estimate[[i]] <- as.data.frame(trait.estimate[[i]])
trait.estimate[[i]]$treatment <- row.names(trait.estimate[[i]])

# outside for loop lapply version
trait.estimate = lapply(component.estimation, colMeans)
trait.estimate = lapply(trait.estimate, as.data.frame)
trait.estimate = lapply(trait.estimate, function(x) x$treatment = row.names(x))

# all in one lapply version with anonymous function
trait.estimate = lapply(component.estimation, function(x) {
  means = colMeans(x)
  means = as.data.frame(means)
  means$treatment = row.names(means)
  return(means)
})
```

Which is better? I'll leave that to you to decide. Use whichever you prefer.